# How to initialize 3 dimension vector with the size in C++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

For example, if we initialize `vector<vector<vector<double>>> f`, the dimension in each direction is not specified. So, I am wondering, what command should we insert to make `f` have size of `[3][4][5]`. Do we use new or something else?

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
vector<vector<vector<double>>> f(3, vector<vector<double>>(4, vector<double>(5)));
```

Comment: Don't forget to space out the closing brackets.

Comment: @Beta, Pre-C++11 at least.

Comment: @Beta The code is [good as written](http://ideone.com/B4dYFG) with reasonably modern compilers.

Comment: Isn't this ugly AF? Can't it be deduced that as you step through the constructor arguments that the type will be one less instance of "vector"? Imagine doing this with a 16 dimensional matrix...

Comment: Yeah, really wish there was an easier way to instantiate an N dimensional data structure for vectors, feels like a common enough use case, and the equivalent with arrays is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already declared the vector and you want to initialize it, this is one way you can do it:

```
vector<vector<vector<double>>> f;
f = vector<vector<vector<double>>>(3, vector<vector<double>>(4, vector<double>(5)));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> f(3, std::vector<std::vector<double>>(4, std::vector<double>(5,0.0)));
```

For anyone who wants it without namespace std.  Also the values in this f[3][4][5] are initialised to 0.0 which might be useful.

Comment: They'll already be initialised to zero. This is the same answer as that which Igor posted 6 years ago, just unnecessarily more verbose.

Comment: Though without `using namespace std` is better coding style.